# how can I detect which combobox state changed?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have two `JComboBox` in a form and I added an `ItemListener` to them and I should overwrite `itemStateChanged()`, now I wanna say if the first `JComboBox` items selected do something and else if the second `JComboBox` items selected do another thing, but I don't know how? Maybe code can help you.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
   picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
}
```

In the second line of code I don't know how to recognize which `JComboBox` state has changed.

Comment: `e.getSource()` may help you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ItemEvent#getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

Example:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

if(e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox){
  JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
  //rest of code
}
```

Now for distinct `combo1` from `combo2` , you have 2 options , you can set names to that components like this.

```
combo1.setName("combo1");
combo2.setName("combo2");
```

And in the itemListener

```
if(e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox){
  JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

   if("combo1".equals(combo.getName())){
        // your code
   }
    .
    .// rest of code
}
```

Or if you know that they are the same instance, then you can always use `==`.

```
   if(combo1 == e.getSource() ){
        // your code
   }else if (combo2 == e.getSource()){
        //code for combo 2
   }
```

Comment: worth noting that even the standard `ActionEvent` has a `.getSource()` method. Also, best practice for events is to have them be `final` in the method signature.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do that, the first is to check the source on the event object and see which combo box it matches to.

The alternative is to add a different listener into each combo box, then you know that any calls going into one listener are from the corresponding control. This is a good use for an anonymous inner class.